# Перенос строки в TextBox, UWP

Tags: c#, uwp

На `Grid`-е у меня есть `TextBox`:

```
<TextBox x:Uid="tboxWriteAMessage" Name="TboxInput"  Margin="5" SelectionStart="0" Grid.Column="0"
         IsReadOnly="False" Style="{StaticResource TextBoxStyle1}" MinHeight="50" TextWrapping="Wrap"
         TextChanged="TboxInput_TextChanged" GotFocus="TboxInput_GotFocus" LostFocus="TboxInput_LostFocus"
         KeyDown="TboxInput_KeyDown" KeyUp="TboxInput_KeyUp"/>
```

При вводе строки, длина которой превышает ширину текстового поля, она переводится на новую строку. С этим все нормально. Однако я не могу сделать так, что бы каретка переводилась на новую строку при нажатии определенных кнопок.

Я пытался сделать это так:

```
TboxInput.Text += Environment.NewLine;
```

Только это работает не так как нужно - переводит каретку в самое начало текстового поля.

Answer (score 1):

В общем, все оказалось просто. Надо было использовать такой код:

```
TboxInput.Text += "\n";
TboxInput.SelectionStart = TboxInput.Text.Length;
```

Хотя и с этим вариантом не все хорошо, поскольку нельзя сделать новый перенос строки, если данная строка пуста. Также нельзя узнать длину самой длинной строки.

**Обновление**

Оказывается, узнать длину самой длинной строки можно просто по тексту:

```
var strArray = TbMessage.Text.Split(new char[] {}, StringSplitOptions.None);
var maxLength = strArray.Max().Length;
```